# How to cache data in JavaScript for non-sequential shifting range?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, caching

**Edit:** For simplicity, and in order to try and make this question and the sample code more generic, I left out a detail. A detail which, in light of one of the responses (which was great), turns out to be important. This system will be used primarily to show things within a date range. The low/high numbers in the code will often represent Unix timestamps the range of which could span weeks or months. **End Edit**

I have a page where I provide a view of data objects which have properties that fall within a certain range. As the user interacts with the view to change it, it generally is a sequential change to the range (0-9, 10-19...). I am retrieving this data from the server, and as it comes in I cache it such that a subsequent request for data in that range is already available. On each read of the data, I first check to see if I have the cache data, and if not I read it from the server and adjust the cache.

A crude, overly simplified example is here:

```
var cache, haveCache, read;

cache = {
    rangeLow: 0,
    rangeHigh: 10,
    data: [
        //whatever has been read so far between current low and high
        {
            low: 1,
            high: 3,
            // ...other props
        },
        {
            low: 5,
            high: 6,
            // ...other props
        },
        //...
    ]
};

haveCache = function( low, high )
{
    return ! ( low < cache.rangeLow || high > cache.rangeHigh );
};

read = function( low, high )
{
    var data;

    if( ! haveCache( low, high ) )
    {
        //go to outside source and read in info , then merge to cache
        //
        // when merging to cache:
        //    if `low` param is lower than `cache.rangeLow`, overwrite cache.rangeLow with `low`
        //    if `high` param is higher than `cache.rangeHigh`, overwrite `cache.rangeHigh` with `high`
    }

    //read data from cache

    return data;
};
```

This works great as long as the change in range really is sequential. However, I realized there is a way to change the view non-sequentially and skip a large set of values. So Let's say I am currently showing for ranges 10-19, and I have a cache holding for ranges 0-29. Then the user asks for a view of data for range 60-69. The way it currently works, I'll ask the server for data and get it back and present it fine. But now the cache rangeLow and rangeHigh run from 0-69 while it only actually holds data for ranges 0-29 and 60-69. Items with properties ranging 30-59 are not in the cache and will never be retrieved.

What (better, efficient) mechanism or algorithm can I use to store cached information and determine whether my current displayed range is in the cache?

Thanks very much,
Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have "chunks" of data with a range of 10 objects each. Calculate how many of these chunks you can store in your cache, let's call this `cache_size`. Now you can use a list of chunks you have in your cache, f.e. for `cache_size` 4:

```
20-29
0-9
40-49
30-39
```

It will be a bit more complicated this way to maintain this list and to check if a certain object is in the cache, but I think it's worth the effort.

You might also think about keeping a time or date index with each chunk to determine when an object from it was retrieved the last time so when your cache is full and you'll have to discard a cached chunk, you can discard the oldest.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're saying. I didn't explain it properly, but the incoming low/high could overlap any of the previous range requests, complicating matters further. Thus, your version could cause me to have to request portions of data which I already retrieved. That said, I can definitely see where that would simplify things and I may go that route anyway.  Thanks, I'll get back to ya.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, it is the one I chose.  It is not the option I was hoping to go with originally as it will cause me to re-requests data I already have if a new range overlaps a portion of a cached ranged, but it's good enough for now to avoid many many extra server requests.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should change your haveCache to have more flatten key=>values.

For example one could be instead:

```
1..4
5..7
10..14
```

Just:

```
1,1,1,1,   // means like 1=>true,    2=>true,   3=>true,   4=>true
1,1,1,     // means like 5=>true,    6=>true,   7=>true
0,0,       // means like 8=>false,   9=>false
1,1,1,1,1  // means like 10=>false, 11=>false, 12=>false, 13=>false, 13=>false
```

Then you just change your haveCache function to determine is you have cache on any range.
And on cache update you also need update your new cache index by filling/adding needed values by 1.

### For the timestamps case

You just should to flatten in another view:

```
var cache = {
    1304960585 : {/* your data for 1304960585 */},
    1304960586 : {/* your data for 1304960586 */},
    1304960999 : {/* your data for 1304960999 */},
};
// then in haveCache function you should have something like:
function haveCache(start, end) {
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        if (undefined == cache[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

For the cases when you have part of the range in cache and part not -- you should invent for your own.

Comment: +1 Yes, that would be a great approach. My only issue there is that in my attempt to make the question and sample code more generic and simple, I removed a detail which is important to your solution: more often than not, this system will be displaying things which fall within a date range, and the low/high numbers will be unix time stamps the range of which could span weeks or months. The bit mask for such a thing could get incredibly long!

Comment: Thanks very much. I like what you're doing there, but I had to go with a different answer given my current constraints and time pressures. It is working and avoiding many extra server requests, but isn't a 1005 effective solution. I will come back around to this some time when I have the time to make it function better.

Answer (score 1):

I'd change the havecashe

```
haveCache = function( low, high )
{
    if( low < cache.rangeLow || high > cache.rangeHigh )return undefined;
    for(var i = 0;i<cashe.data.length;i++){
        if( !(low < cache.data[i].low || high > cache.data[i].high) )
             return cache.data[i]
    }
    return undefined;
};
```

this also returns the data element in the cashe so you don't need to search again

```
var data;
if((data=haveCashe(low,high))==undefined){
    //read from server and store in cashe
}
return data;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't see where this addresses any of the actual problem. Could you clarify?

Comment: it improves your cash lookup so you can see 20-29 is not part of the cashed data when it has 0-10 and 60-69 in it, though honestly there are better ways